# How to Import linear_algebra Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-import, jupyter-notebook, python-module

I am having some difficulty trying to get the linear_algebra module working on Jupyter Notebook in Python. I am trying:

```
import linear_algebra
```

But I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-7080be6cdc0f> in <module>()
----> 1 import linear_algebra

ImportError: No module named 'linear_algebra'
```

I don't get what I am doing wrong

Thank you in advanced for help

Comment: What library is this? How did you install it? Can you import it from the terminal?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is what I was given # Import modules here -->

from linear_algebra import shape, get_row, get_column, make_matrix, \
    vector_mean, vector_sum, dot, magnitude, vector_subtract, scalar_multiply, distance

# Display all plots inline -->
%matplotlib inline

Comment: When I first installed Python and Jupyter Notebook it automatically worked. I had to download it again because an automatic update on my Windows 10 laptop caused Jupyter Notebook to stop working and now linear_algebra is not working on my second download (on another user login on my laptop) - I had used this exact same code when I first downloaded Python and it worked. Everything else is working as in  the first download except the linear_algebra module.

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions. Regardless, these details belong *in the question* not the comments. You can edit your question and add more detail, it will help it gain traction.

Comment: Reinstall `linear_algebra`. Make sure to install it for the same interpreter that Jupyter is using to execute the notebook.

Comment: @ Bakuriu Thank you for your reply. Sorry I am new to Jupyter, how can I reinstall it?

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry, I don't know the answer to any of your questions that's why I can't answer them - I am new to this stuff all I know is that it should be importing with the code I provided in the question. I'm not sure what is meant by library or terminal and I haven't installed linear_algebra yet.

Answer (score 1):

The 'linear_algebra' is not a library so you can't simply import it as such. It is a file that has the functions (eg. dot) so you have to make sure your main code file and the `linear_algebra.py` is at the same directory. I hope this helps.

Comment: The best method is to make the path of linear_algebra.py visible to the Python script. If linear_alegbra.py is stored in the folder, C:\Python_Stuff, then add this in code "import sys followed by sys.path.append(r"C:\Python_Stuff")"